# What is the point of .ix indexing for pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

For the Series object (let's call it s), pandas offers three types of addressing.

s.iloc[] -- for integer position addressing;

s.loc[] -- for index label addressing; and

s.ix[] -- for a hybrid of integer position and label addressing.

The pandas object also performs ix addressing directly.

```
# play data ...
import string
idx = [i for i in string.uppercase] # A, B, C .. Z
t = pd.Series(range(26), index=idx) # 0, 1, 2 .. 25

# examples ...
t[0]              # --> 0
t['A']            # --> 0
t[['A','M']]      # --> [0, 12]
t['A':'D']        # --> [0, 1, 2, 3]
t.iloc[25]        # --> 25
t.loc['Z']        # --> 25
t.loc[['A','Z']]  # --> [0, 25]
t.ix['A':'C']     # --> [0, 1, 2]
t.ix[0:2]         # --> [0, 1]
```

So to my question: is there a point to the .ix method of indexing? Am I missing something important here?

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Comment: With an integer index, `sr[1])` and `sr[1:2]` refer to 2 different index collections, they are likely to yield a different row, a source of confusion and mistakes. This was true also for `ix`, as it used this construction too. As of 1.0.0 previously deprecated `ix` has been [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html) from `Series` and `DataFrame` and must be replaced by a more explicit construction, to tell what is desired in term of index (array-like index /`iloc` or dictionary-like key /`loc`) for each dimension of the underlying values array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

For a `Series`, `.ix` is equivalent of `[]`, the `getitem` syntax. `.ix/.loc` support multi-axis indexing, which for a Series does not matter (only has 1 axis), and hence is there for compatibility.

e.g.

```
DataFrame(...).ix[row_indexer,column_indexer]
Series(...).ix[row_indexer]
```

`.ix` itself is an 'older' method that tries to figure out what you want when presented with label or positional (integer) indexing. This is why `.loc/.iloc` were introduced in 0.11 to provide indexing choice by the user.

Comment: With an integer index, `.ix` and `[]` are not exactly the same. Eg `s[0:3]` is up to item two (so location based logic), while `s.ix[0:3]` includes item three (label based logic).