# What is the difference between these two Python pandas dataframe commands?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have an empty pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
m = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,100), columns=range(1,100))
m = m.fillna(0)
```

What is the difference between the following two commands?

```
m[2][1]
m[2].ix[1] # This code actually allows you to edit the dataframe
```

Feel free to provide further reading if it would be helpful for future reference.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838395/what-is-the-point-of-ix-indexing-for-pandas-series

Comment: Aside from the above you should look at why the first line may fail and the second one works: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you probably shouldn't do either of these (see @EdChum's link for the reason):

```
m[2][1]
m[2].ix[1]
```

You should generally use a single `ix`, `iloc`, or `loc` command on the entire dataframe anytime you want access by both row and column -- not a sequential column access, followed by row access as you did here.  For example,

```
m.iloc[1,2]
```

Note that the 1 and 2 are reversed compared to your example because `ix/iloc/loc` all use standard syntax of row then column.  Your syntax is reversed because you are chaining, and are first selecting a column from a dataframe (which is a series) and then selecting a row from that series.

In simple cases like yours, it often won't matter too much but the usefulness of `ix/iloc/loc` is that they are designed to let you "edit" the dataframe in complex ways (aka set or assign values).

There is a really good explanation of `ix/iloc/loc` here:

[pandas iloc vs ix vs loc explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation)

and also in standard pandas documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html